# Discussion on reopening a specific question: "Do tenses in a time clause never back-shift in reported speech?"

Tags: discussion, question-closure, canonical-question

The question [Do tenses in a time clause never back-shift in reported speech?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112528/do-tenses-in-a-time-clause-never-back-shift-in-reported-speech) (which I'll call *The Backshift Question* or TBQ for convenience) has [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/112688/142322) that could be considered canonical for *back-shifting in reported speech* questions. I've just referred [someone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303682/from-direct-to-indirect-speech) to that answer and voted to close their question as a duplicate of TBQ.

In doing so, I found that TBQ was closed as "not a real question", or in greater detail, "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

After looking at Shoe's answer, I consider the question unambiguous, precise, complete, of useful breadth, genuine, and reasonably answered in its current form. In short, I submit that it is a *real question* and I would like to drum up some support to reopen it, with a view to making it a canonical Q&A for *back-shifting in reported speech* questions.

[Here is a sample canonical ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker). I haven't found an equivalent for ELU. The ELU community seems to be able to find good examples for many recurring questions, but with the recent comments in ELUm about the number of low-quality ELU questions, I'd like to explore the idea of gathering a collection of canonical answers and presenting that list in the [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page.

---

**Update** ([Thanks @Shoe](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7667/discussion-on-reopening-a-specific-question-do-tenses-in-a-time-clause-never-b?noredirect=1#comment31283_7667)) [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/241582/142322) is a more comprehensive post to serve as a canonical answer for back-shift questions.

Comment: The first three paragraphs of this are sensible enough, but the fourth is pointless. If you have enough rep, you can vote to re-open directly, and if not those who can are unlikely to be swayed by  your vote on a meta question. The last sentence is also a duplicate of  [What is a 'canonical answer'?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7115/8019).

Comment: @TimLymington Thanks, particularly for the link. I've reworded the last paragraph of my question to better express my thoughts about canonical posts.

Comment: You make a good case. I've cast my reopen vote.

Comment: I've just voted to reopen it. Good luck.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the suggestion. Hellion beat me to it and even did an extensive edit. Also Dan and Rathony - thanks for voting to reopen.

Comment: You link to an answer I gave about backshift, one of several that I have written on the topic. If the idea of a canonical post is to be pursued, a better starting point might be the following answer, in which I cite various authoritative sources:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240479/problem-with-backshift-in-reporting-clauses/241582#241582

Comment: @Shoe Thanks - I've added the link as an update to the post.